# Copy invocation-list from one delegate to another

Tags: .net, events, delegates

I'm using the expression-builder pattern to build an object. One of the things the expression-builder configures on the object is event-handlers. Here is some demonstrative pseudo-code:

```
public class TargetObject
    {
        public event Action SomeEvent;
    }

    public class ObjectBuilder
    {
        private Action handler;

        public TargetObject GetObject()
        {
            TargetObject target = new TargetObject();
            target.SomeEvent += handler;

            return target;
        }

        public ObjectBuilder AddHandler(Action handler)
        {
            this.handler += handler;
            return this;
        }
    }
```

What I would like is, rather than write:

```
this.handler += handler;
```

To transfer the invocation-list encapsulated by the "handler" member in ObjectBuilder, to "SomeEvent" in target. Otherwise, ObjectBuilder will not get garbage-collected because my TargetObject's "SomeEvent" will hold a reference to the ObjectBuilder's "handler".

Is this possible?

EDIT:
As requested, here is some sample code that consumes these classes:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TargetObject target = new ObjectBuilder()
                .AddHandler(DoSomething)
                .GetObject();
        }

        private static void DoSomething()
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the two objects of the same type?

Comment: A delegate is an immutable reference-type. The returned `TargetObject` will *not* prevent the `ObjectBuilder` instance that created it from being GCed. The `handler` field holds a *reference* to some delegate instance *elsewhere* on the heap. This reference is *copied* when you do  `target.SomeEvent += handler;` In other words, `target` has no knowledge of this `ObjectBuilder` at all, and will not hold a reference to it, either directly, or through its (presumably) delegate-field for its event-handler.

Comment: No, this is not correct. Delegates are a common source of memory leaks. As you yourself wrote, the handler field holds a reference to a delegate on the heap. In this case, the referenced delegate is a member of the ObjectBuilder class, which means ObjectBuilder will not be GCed so long as this reference exists.

Comment: @joniba: "Delegates are a common source of memory leaks" because delegates need access to the the code some where when it's invoked. That's why it has a target field. That's why a delegate needs to hold a reference somewhere. BUT, unless the handler you pass to AddHandler is defined in ObjectBuilder, the target object don't hold  the Object Builder.

Comment: @joniba: Please post the code where you call AddHandler and GetObject. I wrote a simple test app and couldn't reproduce any leaks.

Comment: @Kai Wang: I've added the requested sample code. How did you test for the leak? As you said, if "the handler you pass to AddHandler is defined in ObjectBuilder", the target object holds a reference to ObjectBuilder. Notice that in the sample code, the handler IS defined in ObjectBuilder.

Comment: @joniba: I was using .NET Memory Profiler along with watching Task Manager. How did you know your code has a leak and the leak is actually caused by the reason you said? Did you use windbg to see the mamaged heap?

Comment: @Kai Wang: When I mentioned leaks I was speaking generally. I meant that not removing event handlers (using -=) is a common cause for leaks because people don't realize that event handlers hold reference to the objects that subscribe to them. I don't see this as being the issue in this case. Are you suggesting that when I write someObject.EventHandler += someOtherObject.Handler, someObject does not hold a reference to someOtherObject? If you really think that perhaps we should both start citing sources...

Comment: @joniba： you are confused by the concepts of "event" and "delegate". I don't need to cite any sources when I can just see what's in the managed heap. In fact I would like to see you show an example where the memory usage actually keeps growing.

Comment: @Kai Wang: In this case memory usage would not keep growing. I never suggested that, nor was it the reason I posted this question. I don't really see how this relates to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure ObjectBuilder is not GC-ed because TargetObject instance is holding its "handler" field? delegate is immutable, this.handler += handler will create a new Action instance.

Comment: Please see my last comment in response to Ani's comment. You are right that a new delegate instance is created, but this new instance references a member of the ObjectBuilder instance.

Comment: @joniba: I wrote a test app and couldn't find any leaks using Memory Profiler.